# Wordpress template suddenly not displaying - permalink issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm having a strange issue with one of my pages where in the backend I have a custom template selected but it's showing the single.php for the associated page.

The template worked absolutely fine before and when I changed the url of the page to something else, suddenly the template appears on the live site. But now I change the url back and it doesn't show again.

I've tried resetting permalinks and made sure that my htacess file has the right configuration but still no luck. Obviously it's not convenient to have to keep changing the page url! Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: try to change that page's slug

Comment: maybe you have the duplicate of that slug in posts, pages, or even trash